# Revert back to the previous version of a specific time in a temporal table of MariaDB

Tags: mariadb

I have a MariaDB temporal table as shown in below.

**Schema**:

```
MariaDB [teamdb]> DESCRIBE t2;
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+---------------------------+
| Field | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra                     |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+---------------------------+
| id    | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment            |
| x     | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |                           |
| y     | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    | WITHOUT SYSTEM VERSIONING |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+---------------------------+
```

**Data (Current)**:

```
MariaDB [teamdb]> SELECT * FROM t2;
+----+------+------+
| id | x    | y    |
+----+------+------+
|  1 |    1 |    1 |
|  2 |    2 |    2 |
|  3 |    3 |    4 |
|  4 |    5 |    4 |
+----+------+------+
```

**Data (with History)**:

```
MariaDB [teamdb]> select *, ROW_START, ROW_END from t2 FOR SYSTEM_TIME ALL;
+----+------+------+----------------------------+----------------------------+
| id | x    | y    | ROW_START                  | ROW_END                    |
+----+------+------+----------------------------+----------------------------+
|  1 |    1 |    1 | 2019-08-15 06:41:18.684508 | 2038-01-19 03:14:07.999999 |
|  2 |    1 |    2 | 2019-08-15 06:41:18.684508 | 2019-08-15 06:42:11.661167 |
|  2 |    2 |    2 | 2019-08-15 06:42:11.661167 | 2038-01-19 03:14:07.999999 |
|  3 |    3 |    4 | 2019-08-15 06:41:18.684508 | 2038-01-19 03:14:07.999999 |
|  4 |    5 |    4 | 2019-08-15 06:41:18.684508 | 2038-01-19 03:14:07.999999 |
+----+------+------+----------------------------+----------------------------+
```

**Question:**
I wanted to revert back the record (`id=2`) to the version which was in `2019-08-15 06:42:10.661167` timestamp. That means, after the update, record #2 should have `x = 1` again.

I tried inserting with `ON DUPLICATE` as shown in below query,

```
INSERT INTO t2 (id,x,y) 
  SELECT t.id,t.x,t.y 
  FROM t2 t 
  FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF TIMESTAMP '2019-08-15 06:42:10.661167' 
  WHERE t.id=2 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE x=t.x, y=t.y;
```

This gave me the error saying there is a syntax error.

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version 
for the right syntax to use near 'SYSTEM_TIME AS OF TIMESTAMP '2019-08-15 06:42:10.661167' WHERE t.id=2 ON DUPLICA' at line 1
```

According to the error, it seems MariaDB does not identify `FOR` clause in select inserts.

Any other way to revert back to the other version using a query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not about identifying `FOR` clause, but about the placement of the table alias.

```
INSERT INTO t2 (id,x,y) 
  SELECT t.id,t.x,t.y 
  FROM t2
  FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF TIMESTAMP '2019-08-15 06:42:10.661167' t
  WHERE t.id=2 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE x=t.x, y=t.y;
```

Note the relocation of `t` to the end the system time clause.